# Unable to run migrations VS2015 community edition

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-migrations

I've recently tried to make some updates to an ASP MVC project and I can no longer run migrations. This was working fine previously - not sure whats happend that I'm now getting the following error

```
PM> update-database

update-database : The term 'update-database' is not recognized as the
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is     
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ update-database
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (update-database:String) [],     CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What could possible be wrong? This has started after a fresh repo pull. I've tried restarting visual studio but no joy.

Comment: any solution found?:)